# Is there a way to upper-case a selected text?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gedit, gtk3

I use gedit text editor;
in this application I can easily change the case of a selected text:

- all UPPER case
- all lower case
- invert case
- title case

(screenshot) [image]

The question is: is there a shortcut/tweak/extension to extend this feature, this function to the **whole** system? *i.e. other applications such as Libreoffice Writer and Firefox*

---

I use Arch Linux and GNOME 3.36

Answer (score 2):

Libreoffice writer has the feature. It's at 'Format|Text|Capitalize every word'. There is also uppercase, lowercase, cycle case, sentence case, and toggle case.

Allowing this feature to the whole system is on another level. It's more an application feature.

Comment: thank, LO writer was a **bad** example; what about firefox?

Comment: FF has, fortunately, an add-on that should do the trick. I didn't test it...

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/change-case/?src=search